# UISearchBar bottom line

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios

How can I remove UISearchBar bottom line in UITableViewController?

Swift solution also could be applied.

[image]

Here is my code for VC:

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
NavigationController.NavigationItem.LargeTitleDisplayMode =  UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayMode.Automatic;
NavigationItem.HidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false;
var searchController = new UISearchController(searchResultsController: null);
NavigationItem.SearchController = searchController;
NavigationItem.SearchController.DefinesPresentationContext = true;
NavigationItem.SearchController.DimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
```

For **AppDeletage.cs**

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.Translucent = false;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
```

I tried almost all solutions which I've found over the Internet.

Don't work next solutions:

```
UISearchBar.Appearance.BackgroundImage = null;
UISearchBar.Appearance.BackgroundColor= UIColor.Clear;
```

---

```
NavigationItem.SearchController.Layer.BorderWidth = 0
NavigationItem.SearchController.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.White.CGColor
```

---

```
NavigationItem.SearchController.SearchBar.ClipsToBounds = true;
```

Comment: Maybe this line is resulted from `UITableViewController`.You can try to set like this:`[tableView  setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]`.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I don’t think so, but I’ll try

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT, unfortunately no, it's not separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution:

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
    ((UIImageView) NavigationItem.SearchController.SearchBar.Superview?.Subviews.First().Subviews.First()).Bounds = CGRect.Null;
}
```